# Auto-refreshing chat issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I have a `<div id="refresh">` that has some MySQL content in it. I has this JavaScript code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refreshs_contents = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#refresh').load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh').fadeIn("slow");  // load div.refresh
        }
    , 3000); // refresh every 3 seconds
</script>
```

It actually posts a duplicate of the code the first time so it would look like this:

```
    0 seconds
+-------------------------------------+
|Randome Text                         |
|This is such a cool chat room        |
|Not really                           |
+-------------------------------------+
    3 seconds
+-------------------------------------+
|Randome Text                         |
|This is such a cool chat room        |
|Not really                           |
|This is such a cool chat room        |
|Not really                           |
+-------------------------------------+
```

If you noticed that, It left out the post "Random Text". I don't know why.
But yeah, it basically does that the first time. Then after 6 seconds, it refreshes, but doesn't more content, after that, it refreshes right. So I decided to clear the contents of the page right before refreshing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_clearContents = setInterval(
        function(){
            $("#refresh").html(""); //clear contents of div#refresh
        }
    , 3000);  //clear existing contents every 3 seconds

    var auto_refreshs_contents = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#refresh').load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh').fadeIn("slow");  // load div.refresh
        }
    , 3000); // refresh every 3 seconds
</script>
```

However thats when things get weird. I'm looking at the `networks` tab in Chrome Developers Tools and it's showing that it refreshes every 200ms or so (yes 200) and sometimes it takes 2.5 seconds. I have no idea...

Is there something wrong with my code? Is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there must be something wrong on the back end.  [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm82w/) showing basically just what you are saying and it's working fine.

When you see that 200ms, I think that is likely the time that it takes to generate the `index.php` page, not the time between intervals.

If you show us the response from the php page or the php page itself we may be able to help.

Comment: Here is another version that actually shows the number of milliseconds between each `load()`  http://jsfiddle.net/Gm82w/7/

Comment: Does the divs HAVE to be referenced as ID? Or can I have a class on them (because there is multiple) like this:

Comment: Could I do something like this: $('.refresh').load('inc/chat.php .messages').fadeIn("slow"); The reason I ask is because I changed both DIVS to a class because theyre used multiple times. And it's not refreshing now.

Comment: The "Loading Page Fragments" section of [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) say that the selector will ". . . find the element with an ID of container."  Are you able to update your back end to something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm82w/15/)?  It is loading [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCSQM/7/).  As you can see, I'm just wrapping the class elements in a div.